# Here's the song, now tell me the title!

Tags: knowledge, visual, steganography, computer-puzzle, music

You ever have it happen where you know how a song goes, but you forget its title? I've heard you guys are good at figuring stuff out for free, so I'll just drop some notes here
[image] and let you guys do your thing. Just FYI, middle C is C.

Hint 1:

> There are at least **three** layers of steganography (with a small web search at the end, as it will be a song you're likely unfamiliar with), but **it will be obvious at each step** when you have solved one layer and are now working on the next. Feel free to share partial progress!

Hint 2:

> The FYI is not needed until you already have sounds to work with.

Comment: For whoever made the now deleted comment: I presume you found the way forward? I have checked that it works, if you know exactly the format of what you're doing and the constraints of what you've been given :)

Comment: Actually, in retrospect, there was something a little unnecessarily painful about the format of the thing. I've made it a new image which should work with ease as long as your IO is bytestrings.

Comment: Yeah, thanks :) Spoiler for solvers: rot13([Guvf vf jung lbh trg nsgre pbairegvat erq inyhrf gb ZVQV svyr](https://onlinesequencer.net/2126964))

Comment: Spoilers indeed, but the sharing partial progress is good! What I've learned from all this is that [system-specific bytestring/string translation is the devil.](https://www.snoyman.com/blog/2016/12/beware-of-readfile/)

Comment: @Feryll Just curious, is converting the image to a midi the only computer skill needed in this puzzle? (Because even though I can't write programs, I'd like to have a go at this puzzle)

Comment: @JerryDean Yeah, that's the only computer-based part of it. The rest can be done with your ears, and a pencil+paper. Good luck!

Comment: I have used a stegonagraphy decode tool and now I have   a string.M I on the way ?

Comment: "I analyzed the image file and found a zlib file inside, but now I'm stuck."

Comment: @IlCorsaroNero And what do you normally do with zlib files? :)